# Trying to combine two images, but after overlapping there's visible lines

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

[image]

I get output like the one in the linked image. 
I merged images using cv2.warpPerspective and I'm trying to use Multi Band Blender but I can't find any resources on using that in Python.
Any resources on this or alternative libraries to eliminate this would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to match the one image to the other image using their means and standard deviations. See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/. Sorry, I do not know Multi Band Blender. Best to always show what code you have attempted. See the help forum for what to provide for good questions.

Comment: maybe you can provide your source image